# Conceptually compare C# String and StringBuilders

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

What are some similarities between string and string builders in C#? I only seem to come up with differences between the two.

Comment: They're both used with strings.

Comment: What kind of similarities are you looking for? Or are you asking for a response to an interview question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Probably a University assignment, so don't help! learning how to research problems you're facing is a valuable skill.

Comment: A `StringBuilder` is, conceptually, a conveniently mutable string. Beyond that, the only similarities are superficial and uninteresting (like "both are reference types").

Comment: @Matt pointing someone in the right direction isn't bad. Trying to get in a professor's mind though and understand what trivia they were thinking about ... Ugh.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) may be worth reading.

Comment: Hi Sarah, both have a `ToString()` method

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel so does every type.

Comment: What do you mean by "similarities"? You want to know when to use what and why?

Comment: Both are basically collections of characters.

Comment: StringBuilder tries very hard to not be a string type.  Not its job.

Comment: @Magnus I suspect it's more "what was the prof/interviewer thinking ?". I also suspect even Mads Torgersen couldn't mention many *meaningful* similarities. And those he mentioned wouldn't be the same as the professors

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable which means that every time that you modify it a new instance is created and string builder holds a dynamic memory without reallocating it on every change.

you can see some tips in [dot net perls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder)

there are no similarities, string is an object type and the string builder is a different object.
having said that you can think about the StringBuilder as a string decorator which has some optimizations in it. (implementing the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern))

Comment: This seems to be stating difference, not similarities.

Comment: @juharr that's not the answerer's nor the OP's problem. The problem lies with whoever though up that question

Answer (score 0):

A StringBuilder is a Factory for Strings.

Translation into real world: You are trying to compare a cow with milk.

Comment: I wouldn't call a StringBuilder a Factory, not a the sense of the Factory pattern in programming at least.

Comment: Its a builder, but the nature of strings makes it a factory, as every ToString() is 
(potentially) creating a new instance. But I admit, its not the "classic" factory ;)